# How to read numbers; How to store those numbers in variable; and how to display those numbers in a label; from line edit in Qt?

Tags: qt

I have to read numbers from line edit in Qt Creator, and then divide them by 100 and display them in a label.

The only method I know is:

```
QString OOP_marks = ui->lineEdit_OOP_marks_input->text();
ui->label_OOP_marks->setText(QString(OOP_marks));
```

But the above method cannot read numbers; it reads string. I have tried a lot but can't figure out the code for this part of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about QString `toInt` function, and then static `QString::number` function?

```
QString OOP_marks = ui->lineEdit_OOP_marks_input->text();
int OOP_marks_val = OOP_marks.toInt();
ui->label_OOP_marks->setText(QString::number(OOP_marks_val/100));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QString::toDouble](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toDouble) for converting string to number. If you are planning to accept integers use [QString::toInt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt) instead. To convert number to string again [QString::number](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6) is way to go.

```
const auto& OOP_marks = ui->lineEdit_OOP_marks_input->text();
bool isNumber; // optional
const double number = OOP_marks.toDouble(&isNumber);

const auto& result = isNumber ? QString::number(number / 100) : QString("Please enter valid number.");
ui->label_OOP_marks->setText(result);
```

But I suggest you to use [QSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html) or [QDoubleSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html), instead of `QLineEdit`.

Comment: I want to use numbers from 0 to 100, but QSpinBox can display from 0 to 99 and QDoubleSpinBox from 00.00 to 99.99.

Comment: Both spin boxes has `setMaximum` function. `setMaximum(100)`.